# Jquery Scroll Slow anchor back to header

Tags: jquery

Hay, (sorry for my english)
i wrote this code

```js
jQuery(function(){
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () { //Fonction appelée quand on descend la page
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 ) {  // Quand on est à 200pixels du haut de page,
                $('#scrollUp').css('right','10px'); // Replace à 10pixels de la droite l'image
            }  else { 
                $('#scrollUp').removeAttr( 'style' ); // Enlève les attributs CSS affectés par javascript
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrollUp">
  <a href="#top"><img src="img/to_top.png"/></a>
</div>
```

its a button on my page to go to the Header, but i want the back to header going to slow.
I'm novice in JS and Jquery, anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a behaviour

This does not need jQuery

Also your jQuery function was wrapped in a function, that is not needed

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#top {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="top">Top</div>
<div id="scrollUp">
  <a href="#top"><img src="img/to_top.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: doesnt work, i need a buton for back to the header, to to scroll the head... like example (on the right bottom), 
https://imgur.com/a/eS1JErc
when u scroll down... in the home page.. you have the header...differents section etc... and the button appear after the header, on different section and on the footer to back to the header

Comment: As you can see in the snippet it works. If you put `<a href="#top"><img src="img/to_top.png" /></a>` anywhere, it will go to top if you have ìd="top"` on any element in the header or the header itself

Comment: Your link to the image does not work for me

Comment: i find a solution... simply 

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }

Comment: Yes, that is what I answered.